# Solving for inequality $-1 \leq 4x^2 \leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Bit rusty on my algebra, I'm trying to solve for the inequality of $-1 \leq 4x^2 \leq 1$.
If I divide everything by $4$ I get $-\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$, now you can't take the square root of a negative number so how come the solution is $-\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, can you see why you can get rid of the left part of the inequality?

Comment: So you're saying $-\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2$ doesn't work, but $x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$ does, so you simply do $x <= \pm \frac{1}{2}$ and ignore the left part? @user70925

Comment: I don't say it doesn't work, just that it's vacuous. You only need $x^2\leq 1/4$ to conclude.

Comment: Yeah bad wording on my part :P, thanks! @user70925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to take

$$-1≤4x^2≤1$$

Because, $4x^2≥0$, for all $x\in\mathbb R$. You have

$$0≤4x^2≤1$$

$$\implies 0≤ x^2≤\frac 14$$

$$\implies 0≤ |x|≤\frac 12$$

$$\implies -\frac 12≤x≤\frac 12.$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense !

Answer (score 1):

$ x^2 \geq 0 $ so your inequality becomes $ 0 \leq x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$

You can take the root of this equation, but remember that you have to take both the positive and negative root.

So you'll have:

$ 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $0 \geq x \geq -\frac{1}{2}$

Combine those and you have the result.

An alternate way to think about this is that

$-\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$ implies $|x^2| \leq \frac{1}{4}$, therefore $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ which implies the solution listed.